# XSL Transformation | XML to XAML | Add hierarchy level to nest elements

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, xslt, xslt-1.0

Since the GroupBox Control in WPF accepts only one WPF Control as content I had to wrap all properties into an DockPanel control first.

I used the following xsl style sheet to transform my code into the XAML code snippet displayed afterwards
Style sheet (snippet):

```
  <!-- Default attribute processing -->
  <xsl:template name="process-element">
    <xsl:param name="attr" />

    <!-- Process all attributes and elements which are going to be
             transformed to attributes -->
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|*" mode="to-attr" />
    <!-- Add extra attribute -->
    <xsl:if test="$attr">
      <xsl:attribute name="{substring-after($attr, '|')}">
        <xsl:value-of select="@*[local-name() = substring-before($attr, '|')]" />
      </xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:if>
    <!-- Process children elements -->
    <xsl:apply-templates select="*" />
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- Map GroupBoxWrapper into GroupBox -->
  <xsl:template match="GroupBoxWrapper">
    <xsl:element name="GroupBox">
      <!-- TODO: Add DockPanel Element and move "cursor" one level upwards -->
      <!--<xsl:element name="DockPanel">-->
        <xsl:call-template name="process-element">
          <xsl:with-param name="attr"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
      <!--</xsl:element>-->
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>
```

This is the generated code XAML:

```
<GroupBox Name="groupbox1" DockPanel.Dock="Left, Right, Top, Bottom" Width="1092" Height="125" Background="Transparent" Foreground="#0046D5" Visibility="visible" BorderThickness="1,1,1,1" FontFamily="Tahoma" FontSize="9" TabIndex="0" IsTabStop="False">
  <DockPanel Name="panel4" DockPanel.Dock="Top" Width="1078" Height="25" Background="Transparent" Visibility="visible">
    <Label Name="lblName" DockPanel.Dock="Left" Width="100" Height="25" Background="Transparent" Foreground="Black" Visibility="visible" BorderThickness="1,1,1,1" FontFamily="Tahoma" FontSize="9" TabIndex="0" IsTabStop="False" Content="Name:" />
    <TextBox Name="txtName" DockPanel.Dock="Left" Width="100" Height="25" Background="Azure" Foreground="Black" Visibility="visible" BorderThickness="1,1,1,1" FontFamily="Tahoma" FontSize="9" TabIndex="1" IsTabStop="True" Text="" />
  </DockPanel>
  <DockPanel Name="panel5" DockPanel.Dock="Top" Width="1078" Height="25" Background="Transparent" Visibility="visible">
    <Label Name="lblLastName" DockPanel.Dock="Left" Width="100" Height="25" Background="Transparent" Foreground="Black" Visibility="visible" BorderThickness="1,1,1,1" FontFamily="Tahoma" FontSize="9" TabIndex="0" IsTabStop="False" Content="Lastname:" />
    <TextBox Name="txtLastName" DockPanel.Dock="Left" Width="100" Height="25" Background="Azure" Foreground="Black" Visibility="visible" BorderThickness="1,1,1,1" FontFamily="Tahoma" FontSize="9" TabIndex="1" IsTabStop="True" Text="" />
  </DockPanel>
  <DockPanel Name="panel6" DockPanel.Dock="Top" Width="1078" Height="25" Background="Transparent" Visibility="visible">
    <Label Name="label4" DockPanel.Dock="Left" Width="100" Height="25" Background="Transparent" Foreground="Black" Visibility="visible" BorderThickness="1,1,1,1" FontFamily="Tahoma" FontSize="9" TabIndex="0" IsTabStop="False" Content="Age:" />
    <TextBox Name="textbox3" DockPanel.Dock="Left" Width="100" Height="25" Background="Azure" Foreground="Black" Visibility="visible" BorderThickness="1,1,1,1" FontFamily="Tahoma" FontSize="9" TabIndex="1" IsTabStop="True" Text="" />
  </DockPanel>
  <DockPanel Name="panel14" DockPanel.Dock="Top" Width="1078" Height="25" Background="Transparent" Visibility="visible">
    <Label Name="label9" DockPanel.Dock="Left" Width="100" Height="25" Background="Transparent" Foreground="Black" Visibility="visible" BorderThickness="1,1,1,1" FontFamily="Tahoma" FontSize="9" TabIndex="0" IsTabStop="False" Content="Gender:" />
    <RadioButton Name="radiobutton1" DockPanel.Dock="Left" Width="75" Height="25" Background="Transparent" Foreground="Black" Visibility="visible" BorderThickness="1,1,1,1" FontFamily="Tahoma" FontSize="9" TabIndex="1" IsTabStop="True" Content="Male" />
    <RadioButton Name="radiobutton2" DockPanel.Dock="Left" Width="75" Height="25" Background="Transparent" Foreground="Black" Visibility="visible" BorderThickness="1,1,1,1" FontFamily="Tahoma" FontSize="9" TabIndex="2" IsTabStop="True" Content="Female" />
  </DockPanel>
</GroupBox>
```

The problem is that the GroupBox contains now four elements which is not possible in WPF. That's why I need to wrap those controls into an single DockPanel.

When I uncomment the `<xsl:element name="DockPanel">` line the XAML code Looks like this:

```
<GroupBox> <!-- attributes should appear on this line -->
      <DockPanel Name="groupbox1" DockPanel.Dock="Left, Right, Top, Bottom" Width="1092" Height="125" Background="Transparent" Foreground="#0046D5" Visibility="visible" BorderThickness="1,1,1,1" FontFamily="Tahoma" FontSize="9" TabIndex="0" IsTabStop="False">
        <DockPanel Name="panel4" DockPanel.Dock="Top" Width="1078" Height="25" Background="Transparent" Visibility="visible">
          <Label Name="lblName" DockPanel.Dock="Left" Width="100" Height="25" Background="Transparent" Foreground="Black" Visibility="visible" BorderThickness="1,1,1,1" FontFamily="Tahoma" FontSize="9" TabIndex="0" IsTabStop="False" Content="Name:" />
          <TextBox Name="txtName" DockPanel.Dock="Left" Width="100" Height="25" Background="Azure" Foreground="Black" Visibility="visible" BorderThickness="1,1,1,1" FontFamily="Tahoma" FontSize="9" TabIndex="1" IsTabStop="True" Text="" />
        </DockPanel>
        <DockPanel Name="panel5" DockPanel.Dock="Top" Width="1078" Height="25" Background="Transparent" Visibility="visible">
          <Label Name="lblLastName" DockPanel.Dock="Left" Width="100" Height="25" Background="Transparent" Foreground="Black" Visibility="visible" BorderThickness="1,1,1,1" FontFamily="Tahoma" FontSize="9" TabIndex="0" IsTabStop="False" Content="Lastname:" />
          <TextBox Name="txtLastName" DockPanel.Dock="Left" Width="100" Height="25" Background="Azure" Foreground="Black" Visibility="visible" BorderThickness="1,1,1,1" FontFamily="Tahoma" FontSize="9" TabIndex="1" IsTabStop="True" Text="" />
        </DockPanel>
        <DockPanel Name="panel6" DockPanel.Dock="Top" Width="1078" Height="25" Background="Transparent" Visibility="visible">
          <Label Name="label4" DockPanel.Dock="Left" Width="100" Height="25" Background="Transparent" Foreground="Black" Visibility="visible" BorderThickness="1,1,1,1" FontFamily="Tahoma" FontSize="9" TabIndex="0" IsTabStop="False" Content="Age:" />
          <TextBox Name="textbox3" DockPanel.Dock="Left" Width="100" Height="25" Background="Azure" Foreground="Black" Visibility="visible" BorderThickness="1,1,1,1" FontFamily="Tahoma" FontSize="9" TabIndex="1" IsTabStop="True" Text="" />
        </DockPanel>
        <DockPanel Name="panel14" DockPanel.Dock="Top" Width="1078" Height="25" Background="Transparent" Visibility="visible">
          <Label Name="label9" DockPanel.Dock="Left" Width="100" Height="25" Background="Transparent" Foreground="Black" Visibility="visible" BorderThickness="1,1,1,1" FontFamily="Tahoma" FontSize="9" TabIndex="0" IsTabStop="False" Content="Gender:" />
          <RadioButton Name="radiobutton1" DockPanel.Dock="Left" Width="75" Height="25" Background="Transparent" Foreground="Black" Visibility="visible" BorderThickness="1,1,1,1" FontFamily="Tahoma" FontSize="9" TabIndex="1" IsTabStop="True" Content="Male" />
          <RadioButton Name="radiobutton2" DockPanel.Dock="Left" Width="75" Height="25" Background="Transparent" Foreground="Black" Visibility="visible" BorderThickness="1,1,1,1" FontFamily="Tahoma" FontSize="9" TabIndex="2" IsTabStop="True" Content="Female" />
        </DockPanel>
      </DockPanel>
    </GroupBox>
```

All Attributes which where intent for the GroupBox are in the DockPanel element which nests the inner GroupBox elements.

I need to figure out how to create the DockPanel element (check) and move up to the GroupBox element to call the process-element template.

Any ideas?

Comment: What does your input XML look like?  What does your desired output look like?  What does the template with mode `to-attr` look like? You can't first create the `DockPanel` element and then move outside it to add attributes, so you'll need an alternate approach, and that requires more information from you.

Comment: Just a suggestion, though, you can XML-to-XAML all you want, but in XAML-based technologies there's a thing called `ItemsControl`, which should replace all your repeating label+textbox stuff, given a proper `DataTemplate` and `Data Items` to bind to. I don't think your XSLT-generated XAML is as maintainable as it should be, if you're doing it this way.

Comment: @JLRishe  "You can't first create the DockPanel element and then move outside it to add attributes". What he is trying to achieve is to transform some of the children elements  (which can appear at any position) to attributes in its parent. If he processes everything at the same time he is going to process some elements before these target elements, and XSLT do not allow adding attributes after children are added. So one of the options is to process all these elements with the mode 'to-attr', so they can be processed first and then resume the 'normal' processing. So it is just a way to sort...

Comment: @JLRishe ... elements in a maintainable way. (When I say sort I mean 'processing order' not general sorting)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**PROBLEM**

The process element template was intended to do the following:

1. Transform the current attributes and the children elements of the current element as attributes of the new element.
2. Add an extra attribute using the attr parameter
3. Process children normally.

The problem that you have currently arises because you are appending the attributes in step 1 (<xsl:apply-templates select="@*|*" mode="to-attr">) to the newly created element DockPanel (<xsl:element name="DockPanel">). That is why your attributes are copied in the other elements.

**SOLUTION**

Do not rely on the template process-elements for doing this transformation. Originally that template was written when all the elements at certain point ([XML to XAML transformation using XSLT 1.0 | Exclude specific transformations for some controls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15115826/xml-to-xaml-transformation-using-xslt-1-0-exclude-specific-transformations-for/)) were following a different logic to save repeating code. So if what you are trying to achieve does not follow the previous pattern, you have to modify the process-template or write a different template for GroupBoxWrapper elements.

The following template would fix what you are trying to achieve.

```
  <!-- Map GroupBoxWrapper into GroupBox -->
  <xsl:template match="GroupBoxWrapper">
    <xsl:element name="GroupBox">
      <!-- Process attributes -->
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|*" mode="to-attr" />
      <!-- Create new DockPanel to wrap children -->
      <xsl:element name="DockPanel">
        <!-- Process GroupBoxWrapper chldren -->
        <xsl:apply-templates select="*" />
      </xsl:element>
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>
```

PS. I think you should understand first the code that we [people on stackoverflow] post, before actually using it so you do not have to depend on us every time that a problem arises.